# List Distinct Values from Multiple Lines Per Cell in Multiple Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given a set of rows in a column, let's say D1 - D3, each cell (1-3) contains multiple lines of multiple words.

Treating each word as a 'phrase', how can I list each of the distinct phrases across the multiple rows in this column?

An example of what I mean:

```
 |   D   |
 ---------
1|Hello  |
 |World  |
 |Apple  |
 ---------
2|Apple  |
 |Orange |
 ---------
3|Orange |
 |Hello  |
 |World  |
```

Would output into another column (e.g., `E1`) the following:

```
 |   E   |
 ---------
1|Hello  |
 |World  |
 |Apple  |
 |Orange |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, CHAR(10),
     φ, D1:D3,
     δ, LEN(φ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(φ,CHAR(10),))+1,
     TEXTJOIN(α,,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(α&φ,α,SEQUENCE(,MAX(δ))),α),3))))
```

---

- `α` denotes <kbd>CHAR(10)</kbd>
- `φ` denotes the range of cells in `Column D` `D1:D3`
- `δ` denotes the number of words per cells used `LEN(φ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(φ,CHAR(10),))+1`
- Split by Columns using `TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(α&φ,α,SEQUENCE(,MAX(δ))),α)`
- Using <kbd>TOCOL()</kbd> transforming the array into a single column
- <kbd>UNIQUE()</kbd> function to get unique values
- <kbd>TEXTJOTIN()</kbd> to wrap into one cell using <kbd>CHAR(10)</kbd> as a delimiter
- Last but not least remember to wrap the cells, by hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or from `Home` Tab Click on `Wrap Text` from Group Alignment.

---

You can also use a <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper function called <kbd>REDUCE</kbd>, however using the first method is better,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,DROP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(REDUCE("",D1:D3,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,CHAR(10))))),3)),1))
```

---

The above formulas can be simplified, but i tried to avoid wrapping the <kbd>TEXTJOIN()</kbd> function in the first place since it has character limitations and since we are not aware how large the data will be for OP. However, you could do this as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,D1:D3),,CHAR(10))))
```

---

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,D1:D3),,CHAR(10))))` beauty!

Comment: @P.b Sir, I just wanted to avoid the `TEXTJOIN()` in first place, but I saw you dare to take the risk, so why wait, lets update that, and it doesnt needs the `TEXTAFTER()` btw

Answer (score 1):

This could also be used:

```
=LET(e,CHAR(10),TEXTJOIN(e,,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(e&TEXTJOIN(e,1,D1:D3),e,ROW(1:99)),e),2))))
```